# CakePHP echo $response->number; not showing 0

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a response value that is 0 which is getting passed.  However, when I call `echo $response->number;` I get an empty value in the final output - responseVars:

The output is from an external HTTP post call.

I also tried echo `json_encode($response);` and `echo json_encode($response->number);`

And if the response is above 0 it works fine.

Comment: What is `$response` exactly? Show us a `var_dump($response)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the result variable as an int:

```
(int)$response->number
```

Comment: int does not work, response is 0 its just not showing on the call back for http request I get "responseVars:" no 0.